# Problems with PhP Yes/No and Switch/Case routine

Tags: php, javascript

I have taken over a PhP application that populates events in a MySQL database.

I have modified it so it allows events to have multiple recipients. No issues.

My issue is that when a multi user event is clicked on to update or more importantly to delete I ask using a Javascript function 'Apply to all users on this event?'. Question works fine. I appreciate PhP is server side and JS runs on the client side.

So what I tried is a hidden field in my edit form which defaults to 'adddetails' and if they press yes to the multi user question populate it with addmultidetails (which I verified by making a text field temporarily). You can see from the original `<form>` tage that adddetails is hard coded into the post url as a GET paramter.

```
<form action="data.php?method=adddetails<?php echo isset($event)?"&id=".$event->Id:""; ?>"
      class="fform" id="fmit" name="fm" method="post">
```

// data.php //

```
<?php

session_start(); 

function add($st, $et, $sub, $ade){
  return $ret;
}

function addDetailed($st, $et, $sub, $ade, $dscr, $loc, $color, $tz){
   return $ret;
}

function listByRange($sd, $ed){
  return $ret;
}

function list($day, $type){
}

function update($id, $st, $et){  
   return $ret;
}

function updateDetailed($id, $st, $et, $sub, $ade, $dscr, $loc, $color, $tz){ 
  return $ret;
}

function updateMultiDetailed($id, $st, $et, $sub, $ade, $dscr, $loc, $color, $tz){ 
   return $ret;
}

function remove($id){
  return $ret;
}

$method = $_GET["method"];
switch ($method) {
    case "add":
        break;
    case "list":
        break;
    case "update":
        break; 
    case "remove":
        break;
    case "adddetails":
        break;
    case "addmultidetails":
        break; 
}
echo json_encode($ret); 

?>
```

All the post data as originally posted is correct, however if I try to access the hidden field, updmethod, and changed the data.php to have `$method = $_POST["updmethod"];` my program just freezes without any error messages (I have `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in my modules).

Then I tried another form to store the hidden updmethod so I could just change the `method=` in

```
<form action="data.php?method=adddetails<?php echo isset($event)?"&id=".$event->Id:""; ?>"
      class="fform" id="fm" name="fm" method="post">
```

to be built dynamically but am having no success there either.

I would appreciate any help with this. I am not being lazy. I have spent 2 days working on a problem I thought I could resolve quickly and have read 'tutorials' on Server side/Client side relationship. Tried to understand Ajax etc but no matter what I seem to achieve I then encounter another wall.

I know my problem all stems from the Php/Javascript realtionship and trying to get the response from the Javascript function to my Php....but I am stumped.

I will not be offended if I am told my approach is all wrong, but rememeber I am working with an existing code.

Comment: First, welcome to stackoverflow. Second, could you dump the E_ALL that  your received here? It may be helpful for diagnostic.

Comment: What happens if you check `isset($_POST['updmethod'])`?

Comment: Where/how is your hidden input field `updmethod` created? And your `data.php` doesn’t seem to be doing much right now.

Comment: You can always add more `echo` and `print_r()` to see what PHP is doing (step by step) and where it freezes. And (as CBros said) it  seems your script run only `json_encode($ret)` but `$ret` doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi. SOLVED my problem and as it turns out I used the isset($_POST['updmethod'])? in the switch/case routine. So I let the form call data.php be the same hardcoded addetails as a $_GET parameter and then checked isset($_POST['updmethod']. Also, sorry about the 'diet' data.php. I had reduced it for readability purposes. Probably a mistake on my part. I will be a bit wiser next time.

Comment: Hello again. How do I close this? Thanks. Stackoverflow really is a great resource.

Comment: Well, perhaps my claim of being solved is premature. I bet I have more problems with the Delete function becasue once I ask the questions (Multi User and Are you Sure yopu want to delete?) there is no form being posted so not sure how I will pass the affirmative response from the delete all events question. Mmmmm.